# Complex date formatting in r

Tags: r, date, format, complextype

I would like to know what is a best practice or a neat code if I have a very complex format recorded in Excel. For example

```
   bad_format = c(1969*,--1979--,1618, 19.42, 1111983, 1981, 1-9-3-2, 1983, 
                 “1977”,“1954”, “1943”, 1968, 2287 BC, 1998, ..1911.., 1961)
```

There are all sort of issues some years are recorded as string, others are incorrectly stored such as 1111983 (3 extra 1), other in BC etc.

The output should like this:

```
   correct_format = c(1969,1979, 1618, 1942, 1983, 1981, 1932, 1983, 1977, 
                   1954, 1943, 1968, -2287, 1998, 1911, 1961)
```

I have no idea as how to approach this task or have the capability to write a code in r that could solve it, but I hope someone might have an idea as how to write a neat code which could find these issues and correct it.

Comment: The first code chunk is not valid R code; please edit your post to provide a reproducible example that we can copy&paste to work with.

Comment: This is difficult to write a simple parser to cover all cases. For `1111983` is the correct year `1111`, `1198`, `1983`? Since your date ranges are from BC to recent years, anything is plausible.

Comment: This is just an example of how it is recorded in excel. Very valid question as I am not sure how it can be read in r. @Maurits Evers

Comment: Good comment. The correct year would be 1983. Thanks

Comment: @BoroDega - Why? What's the *consistent* rule you want to apply? What about `"201983"` - I could keep giving examples that are tricky all day. Not trying to be a nuisance, but without some clear guidelines any answer is just going to be a guess and not much use to you.

Comment: @thelatemail. Good questions. The consistent rule I would suggest would be to always retain the last four digits of any given number as that will represent the year. So in your example the last four digits are 1983 and thus 20 should be ignored. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First set `BC` to TRUE if the string ends in `"BC"` and FALSE otherwise.  Then remove non-digits and convert to numeric giving `digits`.  Finally use modulo to take the last 4 digits multiplying by -1 if `BC` is TRUE and +1 otherwise.

```
bad_format <- c("1969*", "--1979--", "1618", "19.42", "1111983", "1981", 
  "1-9-3-2", "1983", "1977", "1954", "1943", "1968", "2287 BC", "1998", 
  "..1911..", "1961")

BC <- grepl("BC$", bad_format)
digits <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", bad_format))
ifelse(BC, -1, 1) * (digits %% 10000)
```

giving:

```
 [1]  1969  1979  1618  1942  1983  1981  1932  1983  1977  1954  1943  1968
[13] -2287  1998  1911  1961
```

Comment: Neat solution for a fairly vague question!

Comment: @MauritsEvers: If you watch GG... you will find a large number of such instances. He's very good at "wonderfully elegant". I've been embarrassed ever since my rep exceeded his since my intelligence has never been his equal. The other place to try might be pkg-'anytime' but I suspect that this sampling of free-form "dates" are too idiosyncratic for Dirk's methods.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck.. just for the clarity why have you put a dollar sign before BC, when you used grepl and last stupid question shouldnt you divide it by 1000 as we need to retain 4 digits. Beside that a wonderful and neat solution. Thanks and highly appreciated.

Comment: The $ matches end of string so it only uses a BC at the end.  If you want to allow BC anywhere remove the $.  `x %% 1000` must always be less than 1000 which is not what you want.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck. Great . Thanks. I am not sure whether I really understood the x %%1000 and if you have time maybe you can give a dummy reply otherwise great answer thanks.

Comment: Consider the example `2018 %% 1000` and `2018 %% 10000`.  The first equals 18 and the second 2018.  Clearly you want the second.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck. Got it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @thelatemail, but perhaps this is a start?

```
bad_format = c("1969*","--1979--","1618", "19.42", "1111983", "1981", "1-9-3-2", "1983",
                 "“1977”","“1954”", "“1943”", "1968", "2287 BC", "1998", "..1911..", "1961")

# Step 1: Remove trailing/leading characters
# Anchor digits to start with either 1 or 2
ss <- gsub("^.*([12]\\d\\d\\d).*$", "\\1", bad_format)

# Step 2: Remove "dividing" non-digit characters
ss <- gsub("\\D", "", ss);
#[1] "1969" "1979" "1618" "1942" "1983" "1981" "1932" "1983" "1977" "1954"
#[11] "1943" "1968" "2287" "1998" "1911" "1961"
```

Comment: My totally naive parser, which isn't as well thought through as your answer - `out <- gsub("\\D","",bad_format); substr(out, nchar(out)-3,nchar(out))`

Comment: @thelatemail Seeing G.Grothendieck's solution, removing non-digit characters first like you did seems to be the more straightforward solution than what I did...